# Which probability measure are there in $([0,1],\mathcal P([0,1]),\mathbb P)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

**Q1)** I know that there are no probability measure on $[0,1]$ when the $\sigma $algebra is $\mathcal P([0,1])$ (power set) s.t. $m([0,x])=x$. Except the Dirac Mass, could we find probability measure on $([0,1],\mathcal P([0,1])$ ?

**Q2)** And what happen if we consider $([0,1],\mathcal M)$ where $\mathcal M$ is $\sigma -$algebra of Lebesgue measurable set ? Lebesgue measure satisfy $m([0,x])=x$ so why don't we consider this "probability" space ?

Comment: for Q1) You can take $m(A)=card(A)$ if $A$ is finite and $0$ otherwise. And as well $m(A)=0$ is $A$ is countable and $m(A)=1$ if the complement of $A$ is countable. (for this one we need that $[0,1]$ is uncountable.

Comment: For (Q1) you can also note that convex combinations of probability measures are again probability measures. So you can construct more probability measures using convex combinations. I don't know if there is a way to characterize all probability measures on this space, though.

Comment: Regarding (Q2): The borel sigma algebra is the 'go-to' sigma algebra in probability because it contains exactly all the sets we would like to be able to measure (open/closed sets, intervals etc.). The lebesgue sigma algebra doesn't add any new interesting sets and only restricts the number of probability measures that exist on the measurable space.